# Integrate manually master changes onto a local branch then merge the local branch with the master

Tags: git

I`m doing a tedious rebase. To make it easier I copied master changes onto my local branch.  So now "basically" I have an up to date local branch with manually applied changes from the master. Now I want to integrate seamlessly my local branch with the master branch. I do not want any unnecessary commits. What should I do?

Comment: commit current changes, push them in master if required, otherewaise, just `git checkout master, git pull, git checkout local, git merge master` will do trick

Comment: @sahasrara62 In this case we will have a merge commit

Comment: What was the rebase you were doing, such that manually adding changes from `master` was helpful? Normally you would rebase your branch onto `master`, so that you'd apply each of the new commits on your branch "on top" of the up-to-date `master`. You probably can still even do that now and those changes in the manual commit might "fall out", depending on the context of those changes.